# Driver not visible from the OS in DAS

Tags: storage, direct-attached-storage

While doing the OS scanning the driver is not visible, causing me to be unable to make a backup (which is offline).

The server is directly attached to the SCSI tape library (DAS environment).  What could be the possibilities?

Comment: what OS do you use? what SCSI HBA? what server hardware? what backup software? does the OS detect anything at all? have you tried calling the vendor support line?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, another quality question from wildchild, you spoil us!

How about some details; OS, hardware, planet you live on, anything would be better than what we have.

Comment: it's windows O.S..and plz don't make fun of me .My question is far better than what guys asking in here like diff btw SAN NAS DAS,which is answered with 100 comments, no offense

Comment: No, not it's really not a better question than that one as at least with that question you can understand it even if it's potentially less complex than your own. In fact your question makes virtually no sense at all.

Comment: I m asking for the possibilities..i dont have exp like you are having.
i 'm 20 and learning things..if you think you cannot answer then don't rather than getting involved in abstruse conversation.

I need explanation on what could be the possible reason for this ..

Comment: Provide much more detail.

Comment: please let me know what all details you want..i will tell you.

Comment: OS is Windows 2003 SP2.

Comment: mean, but justified

Comment: @dyasny - this guy just kept coming back all the time with these barely thought out storage questions - I did lots of handholding including on Chat then found out he was being sold to a big company as a 'storage expert' for $$$ so told him that he needed to do the responsible thing and go do something else, didn't hear from him again.

Comment: @Chopper3 - yeah, I've seen people like these before, their business moel doesn't work for long. They do seem to be making loads of noise nonetheless. If you have free time, I could use it, especially if you're any good with cisco stuff and security :)